# Why papers move instantaneously upwards as they fall?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

Sometime papers or leaves of trees seem to move a bit upwards as they fall.

Why is that so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paper rectangle spinning phenomenon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282710/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Falling paper or tree leaf can exhibit a variety of motion patterns: steady
falling, zigzag oscillation, tumbling, chaotic motion etc. In some cases leaf trajectory could include upward region, for example in a zigzag pattern the end of each segment is slanted slightly upward:

[image: zigzag pattern]

The reason for that is the interaction of the leaf with the [vortices produced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_shedding) by its falling motion. As vortices detach, pressure gradient around the leaf edge cause the light leaf to move upwards.

For example a paper

- Zhong, H., Chen, S., & Lee, C. (2011). *Experimental study of freely falling thin disks: Transition from planar zigzag to spiral*. Physics of Fluids, 23(1), 011702, [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3541844), [ResearchGate pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hongjie_Zhong/publication/252954204_Experimental_study_of_freely_falling_thin_disks_Transition_from_planar_zigzag_to_spiral/links/00b4953baac3f0f223000000.pdf).

contains the following visualization of a falling thin disk as well as its wake vortices:

[image: Images from Zhong et al.]